# Tip of the Iceberg

Tags: fluid-statics, density, buoyancy, volume, oceanography

Is it possible to approximate the volume of an entire iceberg if one happens to know the volume of the visible tip? (Assume the water is perfectly still.) If so, how may that be done?

Comment: The ratios of volumes equals the ratios of the densities. Prove this and you will have your answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The upward buoyancy force on the iceberg is equal to
$$F_{b}=g\rho_{{\rm water}}V_{{\rm under}},$$
in terms of the acceleration of gravity, the density of the liquid phase of water and the volume of water that is displaced by the iceberg (equal to the volume $V_{{\rm under}}$ of the iceberg that is underwater). If the iceberg is floating in equilibrium, this must be equal to the downward gravitational force on the iceberg,
$$F_{g}=g\rho_{{\rm ice}}(V_{{\rm under}}+V_{{\rm above}}).$$
Equating these gives an equation for the underwater volume in terms of the other quantities (all of which are known, including $V_{{\rm above}}$),
$$\rho_{{\rm water}}V_{{\rm under}}=\rho_{{\rm ice}}(V_{{\rm under}}+V_{{\rm above}}),$$
The solution for the unseen volume is straightforward,
$$V_{{\rm under}}=\frac{\rho_{{\rm ice}}}{\rho_{{\rm water}}-\rho_{{\rm ice}}}V_{{\rm above}}.$$
Note that, as expected, this has no physical solution unless the ice is less dense than the water.

Comment: Note: this neglects the density of air because it is approximately 0.1% the density of water. If you want to include that then the first equation should be $F_b = g\rho_{water}V_{under} + g\rho_{air}V_{above}$. This could be useful if you were to repeat this experiment with an ice cube (or other object) floating between oil and water.

Answer (score 2):

An iceberg is freshwater ice. The density of pure ice is about 920 kilograms per cubic meter, or 57 pounds per cubic foot, and the density of sea water is about 1025 kilograms per cubic meter, or 64 pounds per cubic foot. So approximately 10% of the iceberg is above water.

Comment: I think your answer could benefit from a more formal description. I can't quite follow how you got to the 10% part

Comment: @Gallifreyan If you put Adrian’s values into the formula from Buzz's answer you find that the proportion of the iceberg above the water is about $10.24 \%$ (which is probably a greater level of precision than the precision of the original values support, since they will depend on temperature and salinity of the water).

Comment: @gandalf61 then perhaps the formula should be reproduced here as well. Answers ought to be self-sufficient in general, for the same reason link-only answers aren't considered answers

Comment: @Gallifreyan: The difference between the posted values in this answer (1025 - 920) is roughly 10%, hence the approximate part that is _not_ submerged in water.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the ratio of densities rather self evident.